# compression setting for log files in /var/log

Tags: log

For the log files in `/var/log`,
it appears that the `wtmp` and also the rotated `wtmp.n` are not ASCII file and can only be read by the `last` command, so if they are compressed, one has to first uncompress them and then use `last -f ...` to read. The other compressed log files can be easily read using an editor such as emacs since they are ASCII text files.

Is there a way to set "compress" for all other logs files except the `wtmp.n?` 
(I assume that if one uncomments the `#compress` in the `/etc/logrotate.conf`,

```
# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress
```

then all log files will be compressed, including the `wtmp`.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/var/log/wtmp` is not a text file but it's not compressed either. It's a binary file and to decode it you need a dedicated tool called [`rawtmp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/rawtmp.1.html) available with the [sac](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/sac) package.

```
sudo apt-get install sac
```

To access wtmp logs, type in a terminal:

```
rawtmp | less
```

Or to decode the first wtmp archive:

```
rawtmp -w /var/log/wtmp.1 | less
```

**EDIT**: To override `logrotate` compression settings for `wtmp` you just need to edit the /etc/logrotate.conf file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/logrotate.conf
```

To add the `nocompress` directive:

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    nocompress
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 12
}
```

From `logrotate` man page:

```
   nocompress
          Old versions of log files are not compressed. See also compress.
```

Comment: Thanks for informing the sac tool.  Yeah I should write wtmp.x  (the rotated older wtmp files) are compressed, you are right wtmp itself is not compressed otherwise "last" would show unreadable chars.  It surprised me a bit that the #compress in my /etc/logrotate.conf is not uncommented, but all my older rotated log files got compressed, which made me wonder which default setting takes precedence over the settings in /etc/logrote.conf.

Comment: to read uncompressed wtmp.1, you don't need a specific tool such as sac, the plain "last -f /var/log/wtmp.1" command works fine.  but if the wtmp.1 file is automatically compressed into wtmp.1.gz (as appeared in my computer), then I need an extra step to uncompress it.   Do you happen to know a way to let the compute not to compress any wtmp.x files automatically?  (note that reading a binary file wtmp.1 was not a problem even without sac. thanks)

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: just see your reply.  your cool answer is now labelled as accepted, thanks much!